# Filter NDVI polygon region Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I'm trying to get the NDVI specs from a polygon region around SF and the Bay Area but the image isn't working. It is being displayed in a region next to the polygon or just comes out black

My code is as follows and the variable "geometry' is the polygon I have drawn on the map

````
// Get the least cloudy image in 2016-17.
var image = ee.Image(
  l8.filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2017-12-31')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first()
);
    
// Compute the Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI).
var nir = image.select('B5');
var red = image.select('B4');
var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');

// Display the result.
var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, 'NDVI image');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndvi,
  description: 'NDVI_CA',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry
});```
````